# No query results for model INSIDE JOB

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

I want to make a simple task for queue Laravel. I have this error in "failed_jobs."

> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException: No query results
> for model

What did I do wrong?

**Controller**

```
public function addUser(Request $req)
{
    $user = new User;
    $user->name = $req->name;
    $user->username = $req->username;
    $user->email = $req->email;
    $user->password = bcrypt($req->password);
    dispatch(new adduser($user));
    // adduser::dispatch();
    
    return 'added';
}
```

**Job**

```
class adduser implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    
    public $user;

    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = new User;
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->user->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why you need a job to save users like that anyway. ModelNotFoundException comes when you didn't import the User model

Comment: As @kas says, absolutely no need to create a job just to save a model. Jobs are for time-consuming things that you either don't want, or don't need, the end user to be waiting around for it to complete. In this instance, just save the user in your Controller.